# Date entry in selenium using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am finding it difficult to enter date into a date field box. I am using selenium with PhantomJS.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
def dobInfo(driver,dob):
    dobentry = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[5]/label[1]")
    Actions(driver).move_to_element(dobentry).wait(0.3).click().perform()
    driver.save_screenshot("clickedonDOB.png")

    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[5]/input[1]")
    driver.save_screenshot("clickedonDOB2.png")
    elem.send_keys(dob)
```

I have been saving screenshots, and what I can see is that the field is not being selected to show DD/MM/YYYY replacing the Date of Birth Label, when trying to click on element dobentry to then enter dob in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format. I've tried clicking on input and on label, and both do not seem to click but return no error.

xPath
 /html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[5]/input[1]"

returns:

```
< input id="b11eba51-2d36-4fd4-8f73-0bf2bbca3b12" type="date" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" name="dateOfBirth" data-componentname="dateOfBirth" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" data-ddlabel="dd" data-mmlabel="mm" data-yyyylabel="yyyy" xpath="1">
```

The url is https://www.nike.com/gb/launch/ (Have to click on 'join/log' in then 'join now' to get form)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this as a selector input[id="fe49fe96-c81e-452e-b7ae-9a32ab4e5702"] ?

I was able to access the element via jQuery

Comment: the input ID changes every time I access the URL

Comment: ah in that case maybe try using type, like this ->  

input[type="date"]

Comment: thanks i'm close, it sets the value like that however I am unable to click on the element itself using that.